# Why is my string showing null when it is set up like my integer values? (Java)

Tags: java

I'm trying to set up a bug that moves on a wire game. I'd like to include an output where I can have the little bug image show in a line so you can see him moving on output. If I skip the image my program is working how I want. When I include it, the BugFace string shows as null and I can't figure out why.

I originally tried creating only bugFace in the class Bug and in the BugFace method I tried

```
if (direction == 0)
        bugFace = "OO>";
if (direction == -1)
        bugFace =  "<OO";
```

I don't understand what I'm missing. Please see my full code below:

```
 import java.util.*;

    public class Bug 

{

    private int position; //current position the bug is in
    private int direction; //0 bug is facing right, -1 is left
    private String bugFaceR = "OO>";
    private String bugFaceL = "<OO";
    private String bugFace;
    
    public Bug () //Set the initial placement of the bug
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        position = rand.nextInt(21)-11;
        direction = rand.nextInt(2)-1;
    }
    
    //Move the bug one space
    public void move ()
    {
        if (direction == 0)
            position++;
        if (direction == -1)
            position--;
    }
    
    //Turn the bug around
    public void turn ()
    {
        if (direction == 0)
        {
            direction = -1;
        }
        else 
            direction = 0;
        }
    
    //Get the bugs position
    public int getPosition()
    {
        return position;
    }
    
    //Create an icon that shows the direction the bug is facing
    public void bugFace ()
    {
        
        if (direction == 0)
            bugFace = bugFaceR;
        if (direction == -1)
            bugFace = bugFaceL;
    }
    public String getBugFace()
    {
        return bugFace;
    }

    
    public String toString ()
    {
                    
        return "Position:" + position + " Direction:" + ((direction == 0) ? "Right" : "Left");
    }

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Bug bug1 = new Bug ();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String command;  
    
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Bug on a Wire game! To play, please use the following key commands: \nM - Move \nT - Turn around \nO - Output to see position and direction \nE - Exit \n");
    System.out.println("Mr. Bug's starting position is: \n");
    System.out.println(bug1 + "\n");
    
    System.out.println("What should he do?");

    //Below line is to see getBugFace without having to play the game
    System.out.println(bug1.getBugFace());
    
    do
    {
    command = scan.nextLine();
        
        if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("M"))
            bug1.move();
        if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("T"))
            bug1.turn();
        if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("O"))
            {
            for(int i=-20; i<=20;i++)
             {
             if (i == bug1.getPosition())
             System.out.print(bug1.getBugFace());
             else
             System.out.print("-");
             }
            
            
            System.out.println(bug1);
            
            }
        
        if (!command.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))
        System.out.println("Great! Next?");     
    
    }
    while (!command.equalsIgnoreCase("E"));

    System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
}
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify exactly what your expected output is, what is being output instead, and **where** in your code you are getting the unexpected output.

Comment: Also, please show exactly what input you are giving to the console. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set the value of the  `bugFace` string anywhere. Initialize it in the constructor and call your `bugFace()` method each time it turns.